# PHP zipped directory becomes cpgz file when extracted

Tags: php, macos, download, directory, zip

I've checked a few questions before posting, including the following:

- [Zipped file with PHP results in cpgz file after extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454158/zipped-file-with-php-results-in-cpgz-file-after-extraction)
- [PHP Download Script Creates Unreadable ZIP File on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411481/php-download-script-creates-unreadable-zip-file-on-mac)
- [Opening downloaded zip file creates cpgz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495103/opening-downloaded-zip-file-creates-cpgz-file)

While testing on a local server everything worked as intended, however when we uploaded to the live site the downloaded zip files opened as `.cpgz` files.

We're populating a SELECT menu (named "**Conference**") in an html form with the folder names in our "`Conferences`" directory (i.e. Asset_Management).

The PHP concatenates into a link as such:

```
<a href="zip_folders.php?directtozip=' . $_POST["Conference"] . '">Download All As Zip</a>
```

Our zipping code sets up the zip file:

```
<?php
// WARNING
// This code should NOT be used as is. It is vulnerable to path traversal. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal
// You should sanitize $_GET['directtozip']
// For tips to get started see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205141/preventing-directory-traversal-in-php-but-allowing-paths

//Get the directory to zip
$filename_no_ext= $_GET['directtozip'];

// we deliver a zip file
header("Content-Type: archive/zip");

// filename for the browser to save the zip file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename_no_ext".".zip");

// get a tmp name for the .zip
$tmp_zip = tempnam ("tmp", "tempname") . ".zip";

//change directory so the zip file doesnt have a tree structure in it.
chdir('user_uploads/'.$_GET['directtozip']);

// zip the stuff (dir and all in there) into the tmp_zip file
exec('zip '.$tmp_zip.' *');

// calc the length of the zip. it is needed for the progress bar of the browser
$filesize = filesize($tmp_zip);
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

// deliver the zip file
$fp = fopen("$tmp_zip","r");
echo fpassthru($fp);

// clean up the tmp zip file
unlink($tmp_zip);
?>
```

But when I unzip the file it becomes a `.cpgz` file.

**Why might this work on our local server and not our remotely hosted site?**

EDIT: I think the `exec()` command might not be portable, but I'm not sure how to replace that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our server had the `exec` and `fpassthru` commands disabled, so nothing was actually being written into the zip files. Unzipping an empty zip file gave me the .cpgz file.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether or not your local `zip` and server `zip` is the same thing:

```
whereis zip
file /usr/bin/zip
zip -v
```

it's possible that your server have some alias on zip (e.g. `tar -cjf`).

You got `cpgz` file because your archiver is unable to unpack file and tries to pack it to its format `cpgz`. I have such issue when i accidentally name `tar.gz` archive as `tar.bz2` or vice versa.